# Android studio 3.1.2, emulator doesn't run

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run android app on an emulator in android studio 3.1.2 but it doesn't even start I attached screenshot. Although I created new emulator still it doesn't work Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: you want an emulator to run android app? or physical device? this is confusing cause you mentioned "you created new emulator and it still doesn't work"?

Comment: I want to run my app on the emulator.

Comment: Dear, then why you need and usb device to get connected?You don't need device to be connected to run app on emulator. There are 3 virtual devices that goes with name **Nexus blah blah**. select one and run the app. The Connected device will show up when you connect your **real phone with USB cable**

Comment: but When I try to run using emulator it doesn't run after few seconds it automatically disconnects and emulator doesn't even start.

Comment: Check the steps to clear and wipe emulator data and re run again. It also depends on java version you are using. Or else connect the real device and run on the mobile phone.

Comment: ok I will try that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171568/discussion-between-sam-and-riya).

Comment: 11:27 AM Emulator: Failed to open vm 1

11:27 AM Emulator: Failed to create HAX VM

11:27 AM Emulator: No accelerator found.

11:27 AM Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument

Comment: In event log I am getting errors like this

Comment: Excuse me sir, it seems something about misconfiguration of your AVDs. Check official docs at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds and see about hardware acceleration too, suggested by the transcripted error frag. Maybe this can help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406945/android-emulator-atrociously-slow-on-windows-7/38407237#38407237 - best luck